# Spring boot docker autoreload using devtools

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I am working with Spring boot and I am trying to setup an docker environment that updates the application, when I make changes on my own computer.

I have found the Spring boot dev tools is what I need to use, and I have setup this already. But the application never updates the code even when I hit save and can see in the console that it updates.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
#### Stage 1: Build the application
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as build

# Set the current working directory inside the image
WORKDIR /app

# Copy maven executable to the image
COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn

# Copy the pom.xml file
COPY pom.xml .

# Build all the dependencies in preparation to go offline. 
# This is a separate step so the dependencies will be cached unless 
# the pom.xml file has changed.
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline -B

# Copy the project source
COPY src src

# Package the application
RUN ./mvnw package -DskipTests
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)

#### Stage 2: A minimal docker image with command to run the app 
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ARG DEPENDENCY=/app/target/dependency

# Copy project dependencies from the build stage
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.example.polls.PollsApplication"]
```

This is what I have In my **POM.xml** and seems to be working

[image: spring-boot-devtools]

And as you can see, when I hit save, this is the output in the console.

[image]

I have checked inside the container, that the files are updated, and they are.
So my question is - Why is my application not updating with the new code, even tho it says it has changed and the files IS changed? Is it something with my docker?

Comment: That Dockerfile can't be used as a live-reloading environment; it doesn't include any of the original Java source files, PNG renderings of them, or a JDK.  I'd recommend using an ordinary non-Docker Java development environment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this article](https://medium.com/trantor-inc/developing-spring-boot-applications-in-docker-locally-4ec922f4cb45) to be helpful when setting up a Docker environment.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y inotify-tools dos2unix
ENV HOME=/app
RUN mkdir -p $HOME
WORKDIR $HOME
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
dos2unix mvnw
./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005" &
while true; do
  inotifywait -e modify,create,delete,move -r ./src/ && ./mvnw compile
done
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ./.m2:/root/.m2
    working_dir: /app
    command: sh run.sh
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 35729:35729
      - 5005:5005
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should add delegated to docker compose.

*The problem is miss config delegated*:

```
volumes:
  ...  
  - ./authorization-server:/authorization-server:delegated
```

**DockerFile**

```
# FROM openjdk:18-alpine
FROM openjdk:18-alpine
FROM maven:latest

RUN mkdir /authorization-server
WORKDIR /authorization-server

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./

RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

COPY src ./src

CMD [ "mvn", "spring-boot:run" ]
```

**Pom.xml add plugin devtool**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  # networks
  spring-boot-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  micro-service-mysql:
    container_name: micro-service-mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: 'authorization-server'
        # We cannot set user as 'root' if mysql is below version of 5.x: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/129
        MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '311094'
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '311094'
    ports:
        - "3110:3306"
    networks:
        - spring-boot-network
    volumes:
        - ./data/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        - ./data/logs:/logs
        - spring_boot_db:/var/lib/mysql
  # spring boot
  authorization-server:
    container_name: authorization-server
    build:
        context: ./authorization-server
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
        - 9003:9003
    networks:
        - spring-boot-network
    volumes:
        - ./authorization-server:/authorization-server:delegated
    privileged: true
    # deploy:
    #     resources:
    #         limits:
    #             cpus: '0.50'
    #             memory: 1500M
    #         reservations:
    #             cpus: '0.25'
    #             memory: 20M
volumes:
  spring_boot_db:

networks:
  spring-boot-network:
```

Comment: Please use formatted text instead of code for answers, see [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551),